# What is a function that converts any number to a one, while keeping the sign intact?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given a number $x$, I would like an $f(x)$ whose value always equals 1, but keeps the sign of $x$ intact. So if $x = 5$, then $f(x) = 1$. If $x = -13$, then $f(x) = -1$ and $f(0) = 0$

What is the algebraic formula for $f(x)$?

I was leaning towards using mod, but couldn't figure out the correct equation.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want for $f(0)$?  That aside, just use $f(x)=\frac x{|x|}$ for $x\neq 0 $ and define $f(0)$ however you like.

Comment: Are you thinking about the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)?

Comment: Of course the answer is very simple. Thank you so much!

Comment: I suppose f(0) = 0 would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can define the $sgn(x)$ function as follows:
$$sgn(x)=1, x>0$$
$$sgn(x)=0, x=0$$
$$sgn(x)=-1, x<0$$

Another possibility is considering the function:
$$g(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}$$
that is defindened $\forall x\in R, x\neq0$.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot define a sign for 0 so for any number other than 0 you can use f(x)=x/|x|